# I cant give a wave modifier to fluid domain. Help?

Tags: modifiers, fluid-simulation

I have an issue and I am really desperate right now. I am trying to give a shake to my liquid. I have a tube filled with a liquid. The tube is my domain and my liquid is at rest at the beginning. I want to give domain(tube) a wave modifier to vibrate the liquid inside of it. But when I give my domain(tube) a wave modifier, I also must give it an effector otherwise it won't affect the liquid. As you know, I can't select the "domain" and the "effector" at the same time. What should I do?
(My version is 2.82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain is just the area where the water/smoke simulation should be calculated.
You can add another shape (inside the domain) as an effector/collision to manage what you are asking for (for example the wave modifier to move the fluid).

I'm not sure that the wave modifier is the best way to give the water a shake..

check this simulation (I did not used the wave modifier, I just animated the internal cube, the one that is set as effector):

[image]

Comment: That solved my problem thank you so much!